# FastPDFKit: How to search term as whole?

Tags: ios, search, fastpdfkit

I'am using `FastPDFkit framework`, it's great. But when I search text like *"pault 9"*, the function search for each component separated by spaces and results are lists of *"pault"* and *"9"*.

I checked in `MFDOcumentManager.h` there is a note like this:

- `exactMatchOrNot` tell the function if it should match the term as a
  whole or   search for each component separated by spaces.
- Default parameters are `FPKSearchModeSmart`, ignoreCase to *YES* and exactMatch 
  to *NO*."

How can I change default parameter of exactMatch to YES so that I can search "pault 9" as whole term?
Thanks.